# Statsmodels OLS 'inf or NaN' error when there is none in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, statsmodels, anova

My data is looks like this:

```
58.445355   97.668693   126.101506  192.417611  221.809156  289.785785  t0  x5
60.451638   101.626297  130.027950  191.922363  219.977219  296.777197  11  x88
61.961283   104.692036  132.872274  197.605787  225.731945  313.789832  t2  x4
```

The columns are `num1` to `num6` and then `t` and `x`

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
from statsmodels.stats.anova import anova_lm

formula = 'num4 ~ C(t) + C(x) + C(t):C(x)'
model = ols(formula, data).fit()

aov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)
```

This leads to this **error**:

```
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

Though my data frame has no Infs or NANs.

What am I doing wrong?

**P.S.** I have done the exact analysis successfully using `aov` function in R without running into any issues.

### Diagnosis

`data.isnull().sum()`

```
num1            0
num2            0
num3            0
num4            0
num5            0
num6            0
t               0
x               0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: NAN stands for "not a number", what is something like `t0` or `x5` if not a nan?

Comment: Sounds like your columns at the end are being cast to a numeric type on accident.

Comment: @enumaris True. But I am doing an ANOVA analysis where certain variables will not be numbers. Any suggestions?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 How can I force it to retain it as character?

Comment: What is the output of `data.isnull().sum()`

Comment: @maximusdooku I am not familiar with the `statsmodels` package so I couldn't really help you further. I just wanted to alert you to the fact that your data frame does indeed contain data that are not numerical and therefore are `NaNs`.

Comment: @ALollz I have added it now.

Comment: Well, the issue isn't with your data, it's a problem with the model. If you look at `model.summary()` you'll likely notice a few of the standard errors can't be calculated properly, which then leads to that error when you run the anova_lm. To my knowledge, R and Stata drop collinear terms automatically, but `statsmodels` does not. You should check to see how many parameters `statsmodels` estimates and how many are output in your `R` models.  You'll likely need to drop these collinear terms manually in `statsmodels`.

Comment: @ALollz Ah, I think I might as well stick to R for this. :/ I have been trying to shift to Python for statistical analysis, but everything seems to require jumping hoops. But thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Yes, I had the same experience. Though `statsmodels` is powerful, it's just not easy to use for a lot of heavy calculations (absorbing fixed effects for instance, or dealing automatically with multi-collinearity). [This cross-validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116825/different-output-for-r-lm-and-python-statsmodel-ols-for-linear-regression) illustrates the issue you're likely having

Comment: @ALollz Thanks. Kinda disappointing.